# Exception when trying to use custom result object in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to read documents from a MongoDB collection directly into a custom Java object instead of the default Document class

I'm using mongodb-driver-reactivestreams v1.11.0 and Java OpenJDK 11 in a Maven Project.

I found MongoCollection.withDocumentClass(Class) method, but i get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class com.engynya.mongo.model.CustomData (java.util.HashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.engynya.mongo.model.CustomData is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

CustomData.java

```java
public class CustomData extends Document {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 783038647854634579L;

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends Object> m) {
        super.putAll(m);
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        Date date = super.getDate("date");

        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

And this is the find method:

```java
MongoDatabase database = MongoDBConnector.getClient().getDatabase(MongoConstants.DATABASE);

MongoCollection<CustomData> collection = database.getCollection(MongoConstants.COLLECTION).withDocumentClass(CustomData.class);

            FindPublisher<CustomData> finder = collection.find(Filters.exists(DocumentField.DATE.toString()));
            ObservableSubscriber<CustomData> sub = new ObservableSubscriber<>(finder);

            return sub.get(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I'm testing this with a JUnit but when i try to read the read the data e receive the exception.

```
List<CustomData> customData = manager.getData(); //query

customData.get(0); // <- here i have the exception
```